# Rain water leaking from gap between garage back wall and floor

Tags: walls, leak, garage, water-damage, rain

Whenever it rains heavily here where I live, I'll see water leaking out from where the back of my garage wall meets the garage floor. My usual contractor suggested that the cause was use to an improperly sealed vent on the roof of my house above that wall, and he resealed it a few weeks ago. However, with the heavy rain in the area yesterday, I once again started seeing water seeping in from the same spot (though much less than before, fortunately).

1. What can I do to seal up the leak permanently? I'm afraid that the water flowing in is going through the wall, and thus can cause rotting, water damage, or mold growth.
2. What should I do proactively to protect against the above issues, given that water has already been seeping through?

Happy to provide pictures if needed.

EDIT: Adding pictures of the inside, don't have good pictures of the outside, since I'm not sure where in the roof it's coming from.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Pictures good.  Water leaks from a roof/on top can be difficult to locate.  Water will take easy way down and where you see water is probably not right above.  It can travail quite a few feet at an angle before dropping straight down.  Vents are easy fast suspects.

Comment: If you can get a look inside the wall it helps to track the leak (like with a borescope camera). Also, using a hose on specific parts of the roof/wall can help track down where the leak is on the outside.

Comment: Find the source, become a detective and follow the water.

Comment: Pics, inside *and* outside.

Comment: Added some pictures.